# I am exporting data from table convert to CSV, to JavaScript variable. . But getting Error "fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array" . How to do it?

Tags: javascript, php, html, fputcsv

This is my PHP code

```
<?php
require_once 'd:\xampp\htdocs\bpr\pdo_db.php';
$sql = "Select ID,FULL_NAMe,AGE from TRIAL";
$csv = get_csv_string($dbh, $sql);
echo "<script> var_csv='" . $csv . "' </script>";

function get_csv_string($dbh, $sql)
{
    try
    {
        $result = $dbh->query($sql);
        //return only the first row (we only need field names)
        $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($row == null) {
            return "No Data";
        }
        $f = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
        foreach ($row as $field => $value) {
            if (fputcsv($f, $field) === false) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        //second query gets the data
        $data = $dbh->query($sql);
        $data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            if (fputcsv($f, $row) === false) {
                return false;
            }
        } // end record loop
        rewind($f);
        $csv = stream_get_contents($f);
        return rtrim($csv);
    } catch (PDOExepction $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $csv;
}
```

I am getting following error!

[image]

[image]

Instead of fputcsv(), I made my own code. But issue if found when I save the CSV to a javascript variable. Is there any other way to convert the data to CSV and pass it on to javascript?
I will convert this csv to JSON at Client side using javascript

Comment: Pretty much what it says.  Parameter 2 should be an array. `foreach ($row as $field => $value) {` you're looping through a single row, which means `$field` is a simple value, not an array. So `fputcsv($f, $field)` fails.

Comment: So no loop and just `fputcsv($f, $row)` for the field names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to output a header row to CSV with the field names.

This code fails because you're looping through the `$row` array and attempting to write one field header at a time.

```
foreach ($row as $field => $value) {
            if (fputcsv($f, $field) === false) {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

What you want is an array with the field names in it. You can use `array_keys()` for that, so your code becomes

```
if (fputcsv($f, array_keys($row)) === false) return false;
```

No loop required.

Comment: Hi Tangentially Perpendicular, 
Thank you for your answer.
The fputcsv() error is solved. 

But  
csvtrial.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token error is still there. Any suggestions?

Comment: @mohan This is the first time you've mentioned it. There's no reference to that error in the question. That error usually stems from a missing semi-colon or an unterminated string.